# Excel headings as cell data

Tags: excel, vba

I have been given an Excel sheet with some thousand of entries to import in an SQL database.

The problem is that it is not a list that it can be easily imported.

It shows like that:

```
GROUP NAME
itemName Price Order
```

eg

```
Desserts
Chocolate Cake 8.5 1
Butter Cookies 3.0 2
Refreshments
Coke 1.5 1
Water 1.0 2
```

I need to transform the above to

```
Chocolate Cake 8.5 1 Desserts
Butter Cookies 3.0 2 Desserts
Coke 1.5 1 Refreshments
Water 1.0 2 Refreshments
```

so to get all the lines under a title in which group they belong

Is there a way to do that?

I can use Notepad++ and SQL very well

Thank you

Comment: With VBA it would be fairly easy. Without VBA, I don't see any easy way (unless the groups all have exactly the same number of items.) Are the group names all single words? Also -- is it only the items that end with an integer?

Comment: Unfortunately not only single words and the real data have more info and they do not end with integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not positive this will work as-is for your needs, but it should get you in the ballpark. This is a VBA subroutine that will loop through your data and write it out to another sheet in the format you need.

```
Sub transformNastyData()
    Dim transformRange as range 
    Dim readRow as range
    Dim writeRow as range
    Dim groupHeader as string

    'change these to suit your needs
    Set transformRange = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:C20000")
    'the row we'll start writing to in sheetOut
    set writeRow = Sheets("Sheet2").Rows(1)



    'loop through each row
    For each readRow in transformRange.Rows
        'check to see if the value in column B is blank (assuming this is how to identify a group header?)
        If readRow.cells(1, 2).value = "" Then
            'capture the group header
            groupHeader = readRow.cells(1, 1).value
        Else
            'we have a good record, so just write it out.
            writeRow.cells(1, 1).value = readRow.cells(1, 1).value
            writeRow.cells(1, 2).value = readRow.cells(1, 2).value
            writeRow.cells(1, 3).value = readRow.cells(1, 3).value
            writeRow.cells(1, 4).value = groupHeader

            'increment the writeRow
            set writeRow = writeRow.offset(1)
        End if      

    Next readRow
End Sub
```